# create object of opposite strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following object in Javascript:

```
let directions = {
  "vertical": [
    "down",
    "up",
  ],
  "horizontal": [
    "left",
    "right",
  ]
}
```

and need to find a way to create another object from it that looks like this:

```
left oppositeDirections = {
  "left": "right",
  "right": "left",
  "down": "up",
  "up": "down"
}
```

Is there an elegant and efficient way to go about this in JS without using third party libraries?

Comment: OK, thanks for the input.  `directions` is designed as shown so it can be used in the UI to display down and up in a drop down box when vertical is selected in a primary drop down box and then to display left and right when horizontal is selected in the primary drop down box.  As for my own attempt - I didn't know how to begin tackling this problem so posted the question here.

Comment: So, considering there's no huge pile of similar objects to process neither it looks like your data will get changed dynamically, why simple hardcoding that is insufficient?

Comment: I had in mind to use a single source of data, then programmatically manipulate it for any variations needed, such as the opposite directions usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can gain your required result by this approach.

```js
let directions = {
  "vertical": [
    "down",
    "up",
  ],
  "horizontal": [
    "left",
    "right",
  ],
};

let res = {};
Object.values(directions).forEach(([a,b]) => {
  res = {...res, [a]: b, [b]: a};
});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100% !important;
}
```

## Update

You can produce the same result by using `reduce()`.

> The `reduce()` method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on
>   each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

```js
let directions = {
  "vertical": [
    "down",
    "up",
  ],
  "horizontal": [
    "left",
    "right",
  ],
};

let res = Object.values(directions).reduce((acc, [a, b]) => {
 return {...acc, [a]: b, [b]: a}
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100% !important;
}
```